# C# Webview2 WebMessageReceived event not firing anymore after update of MS Edge browser and Webview2 runtime

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webview2

I am developing a WinForms project using VS2022 IDE. as per our requirement I am using Webview2 to embed the browser in our WinForms. web site load properly. my requirement was if user select any data from Webview2 at runtime then I need to capture the html of that selected text. this way i did it and it was working fine.

please see me code which was working for last 30 days.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
        Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 webViewControl = null;
        string selectedHtml = "";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitBrowserControl();
        }

        private async void InitBrowserControl()
        {
            webViewControl = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
            webViewControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

            // Handle the WebView2's CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted event
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += async (s, evt) =>
            {
                // Inject JavaScript to retrieve selected text's HTML by javascript
                string script = @"
                    console.log('Script is running in the browser context!');
                    document.onmouseup = function() {
                        var selection = window.getSelection();
                        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                        var clonedRange = range.cloneRange();
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.appendChild(clonedRange.cloneContents());
                        var selectedHtml = div.innerHTML;
                        console.log(div.innerHTML);
                        window.chrome.webview.postMessage(selectedHtml);
                    };
                ";

                await webViewControl.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);
                await Task.Delay(0); // Yield to event loop
            };

            // Handle the WebView2's WebMessageReceived event
            webViewControl.WebMessageReceived += (s, evt) =>
            {
                selectedHtml = evt.WebMessageAsJson;
            };

            await webViewControl.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);

            // Attach the event handler
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged += CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged;
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.NavigationStarting += CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting;
            panel1.Controls.Add(webViewControl);
        }
}
```

if anyone see my code then they can understand i inject a JavaScript into Webview2 browser which will fire **onmouseup** and store html into a js variable and later push that data to client side by **window.chrome.webview.postMessage(selectedHtml)**

i was getting html data from **WebMessageReceived event**.

everything was working as expected but just **2 days back** my **MS Edge Browser** and **Webview2 runtime** was updated automatically which causes the problem. after update of **MS Edge Browser** and **Webview2 runtime** my **WebMessageReceived** event not firing anymore. last 2 days i searched google lot but still no luck.

Please guys help me to figure out the problem and how to fix this issue as a result **WebMessageReceived** event should fire like before.

my MS Edge Browser current version is **122.0.2365.92 (Official build) (64-bit)**
my Webview2 runtime version is also **122.0.2365.92**

Please tell me if i made any mistake in code. Please help me how to figure out and fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Have you updated the `WebView2`Nuget package to the latest?

Comment: I see `async void` from constructor. ARGH-ARGH. I always initialize WebView2 in the forms `Load` event which CAN be `async void`.

Comment: i refactor my code as per the answer of @user246821 but still no luck. i am using latest release of WebView2Nuget package.

Comment: `selection.getRangeAt(0)`will return an error if there's no selection. Try press 'F12' to go to developer tools and step through your javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The code below has been refactored and shows how/when to use *async Task* and where to use *async void* so that [WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/?form=MA13LH) works correctly.

**Pre-requisites**:

- NuGet package: [Microsoft.Web.WebView2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2/1.0.2365.46) (v1.0.2365.46)
- MS Edge (v122.0.2365.92)

**Note**: See [Release Notes for the WebView2 SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/release-notes?tabs=dotnetcsharp) for more information.

**Create a new Windows Forms App** - I used .NET 8 for testing.

```
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace Webview2DetectSelectedHTML
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2 webViewControl = null;
        string selectedHtml = "";

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await InitBrowserControl();

            //navigate
            LogMsg("Form1_Load - Setting WebView2.Source");
            webViewControl.Source = new Uri("https://www.google.com/search?q=webview2");
        }

        private async Task InitBrowserControl()
        {
            //create new instance
            webViewControl = new Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.WebView2();
            webViewControl.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Fill;

            // subscribe to events
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted += WebViewControl_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted;
            webViewControl.WebMessageReceived += WebViewControl_WebMessageReceived;

            //initialize CoreWebView2
            await webViewControl.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);

            // Inject JavaScript to retrieve selected text's HTML by javascript
            string script = @"
                    console.log('Script is running in the browser context!');
                    document.onmouseup = function() {
                        var selection = window.getSelection();
                        var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
                        var clonedRange = range.cloneRange();
                        var div = document.createElement('div');
                        div.appendChild(clonedRange.cloneContents());
                        var selectedHtml = div.innerHTML;
                        console.log(div.innerHTML);
                        window.chrome.webview.postMessage(selectedHtml);
                    };
                ";

            //add script
            await webViewControl.CoreWebView2.AddScriptToExecuteOnDocumentCreatedAsync(script);

            // subscribe to CoreWebView2 events
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.NavigationCompleted += CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted;
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.HistoryChanged += CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged;
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.NewWindowRequested += CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested;
            webViewControl.CoreWebView2.NavigationStarting += CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting;

            //add
            panel1.Controls.Add(webViewControl);
        }

        private void WebViewControl_WebMessageReceived(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2WebMessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            //set value
            selectedHtml = e.WebMessageAsJson;

            LogMsg(selectedHtml);
        }

        private void WebViewControl_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2InitializationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMsg("WebViewControl_CoreWebView2InitializationCompleted");
        }

        private void LogMsg (string msg, bool includeDateTime = true)
        {
            if (includeDateTime)
                msg = $"{DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss.fff")} - {msg}";

            Debug.WriteLine (msg);
        }


        private void CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationStartingEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMsg("CoreWebView2_NavigationStarting");
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NewWindowRequestedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMsg("CoreWebView2_NewWindowRequested");
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged(object? sender, object e)
        {
            LogMsg("CoreWebView2_HistoryChanged");
        }

        private void CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted(object? sender, Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            LogMsg("CoreWebView2_NavigationCompleted");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Update**:

If you're using .NET Framework v.4.8, in the code above, change all occurrences of `object?` to `object`.

---

**Here's a demonstration**:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply with sample code. i test your code but still same issue that `WebMessageReceived` event not firing. i am using .Net framework 4.8 version. my OS is windows 10. i also test it on windows OS 11. everywhere that event not firing. not getting any solution still. please give me more suggestion to fix this issue. thanks

Comment: It seems to work for me. I've add a demonstration to the post. I've tested it with both _.NET Framework version 4.8_ and _.NET version 8_.

Comment: Please post the screenshot of webmessagereceived event that break points stop there.