Microsoft WebView2 crashes on startup
I have a simple test application to test embedding Microsoft's WebView2 control in a C# application as I want to embed a browser that can invoke Script etc. I installed the NuGet package and then took code from the sample for WebView2:
public Form1()  
{
   InitializeComponent();

   // Initialize WebView and add it to the Window's controls
   WebView = new WebView2();

   ((ISupportInitialize)WebView).BeginInit();
   WebView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
   Controls.Add(WebView);
   ((ISupportInitialize)WebView).EndInit();

   // Show the home page           
   WebView.Source = new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com");
}       

However, this crashes on start-up with the error below:
[0428/164447.586:ERROR:check.cc(382)] Check failed: false. NOTREACHED log messages are omitted in official builds. Sorry!
[0428/164448.301:ERROR:check.cc(382)] Check failed: false. NOTREACHED log messages are omitted in official builds. Sorry!
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in mscorlib.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' in Microsoft.Web.WebView2.WinForms.dll

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78196722/10024425 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/73846538/10024425

public Form1() {
    InitializeComponent();

    WebView2 webView=new WebView2();
    webView.BeginInit();
    webView.Dock=DockStyle.Fill;
    Controls.Add(webView);
    webView.EndInit();

    webView.Source=new Uri("https://www.microsoft.com");
}


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
